# Redirect shell command in a script without loosing special characters

Tags: bash, shell, sed, printf

From another script used as a wrapper I'm trying to configure an AWS SNS alert that will be triggered by the webhook. The issue is that I'm loosing al the specal characters from SED command that will help me eliminate ASCI color characters from some custom commands like 'alerts':

```
printf 'aws sns publish --subject "$(hostname -f)" --message "$(alerts -v|sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' && echo -e "\n\n" && alerts --components|sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g')"' > /opt/webhook/sns.sh
```

Basically I'm trying to redirect this command inside /opt/webhook/sns.sh to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` itself is interpreting the `\x1b`, rather than writing it literally. I would move both command substitutions outside the format string, both for readability and to protect `\x1b` from being interpreted by `printf`.

```
printf 'aws sns publish --subject "%s" --message "%s"\n' \
  '$(hostname -f)' \
  "\$(alerts -v | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' &&
     printf '\n\n' &&
     alerts --components | sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g')" \
  > /opt/webhook/sns.sh
```

You'll note the quoting is tricky; single quotes cannot appear inside a single-quoted string, so I use double quotes and explicitly escape the `$` that starts the command substitution.

I would actually not use `printf` at all, but `cat` with a here document:

```
cat <<'EOF' > /opt/webhook/sns.sh
aws sns publish --subject "$(hostname -f)" --message "$(alerts -v|sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' && echo -e "\n\n" && alerts --components|sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g')"
EOF
```

Ideally, `alerts` would either provide a way to disable colored output or be smart enough to disable color output automatically when its standard output isn't a terminal, so you could dispense with the `sed` command altogether.